# How to Merge Two JavaScript arrays using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to merge two JavaScript objects.

```
device: [{devHardwareId:"40A8F065E465",deviceId:67,deviceIp:"192.168.2.3",deviceName:"DESKTOP-IV0H659"}]

peripherals:[{
    "peripheralId": 3,
    "perHardwareId": "AVtech-Cam",
    "peripheralName": "BackGate",
    "peripheralType": "Video",
    "isActive": true,
},
{
    "peripheralId": 1,
    "perHardwareId": "Logitech-Cam",
    "peripheralName": "FrontCam",
    "peripheralType": "Video",
    "isActive": true,
}]
```

In above examples the device can contains several peripherals. I want to merge it using AngularJs.then it should be like below.

```
 device :{devHardwareId:"40A8F065E465",
deviceId:67,
deviceIp:"192.168.2.3",
deviceName:"DESKTOP-IV0H659",
peripherals:{
    "peripheralId": 3,
    "perHardwareId": "AVtech-Cam",
    "peripheralName": "BackGate",
    "peripheralType": "Video",
    "isActive": true,
},
{
    "peripheralId": 1,
    "perHardwareId": "Logitech-Cam",
    "peripheralName": "FrontCam",
    "peripheralType": "Video",
    "isActive": true,
}
}
```

How can I do that task using AngularJs.

Comment: Why using AngularJs? That's basic JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS has nothing to do with it. You can use simple JavaScript for this:

```js
let device = [{"devHardwareId":"40A8F065E465","deviceId":67,"deviceIp":"192.168.2.3","deviceName":"DESKTOP-IV0H659"}];
const peripherals = [{"peripheralId":3,"perHardwareId":"AVtech-Cam","peripheralName":"BackGate","peripheralType":"Video","isActive":true},{"peripheralId":1,"perHardwareId":"Logitech-Cam","peripheralName":"FrontCam","peripheralType":"Video","isActive":true}];

device[0].peripherals = peripherals;
console.log(device[0]);
```